# Transfer custom (all) metadata using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

How to transfer metadata using FFMPEG or other tools with CMD ?

I'm trying to encode video/audio and since they already have metadata inside obviously i want to preserve them into my new file

btw since i'm using mediamonkey as main player, there's also some Custom metadata. this is the one who wont transfer

- for Video output file using mp4/mkv (using x264)
- for Audio output file using m4a (using neroAac)

Thank You!

ps. which container is best for **neroAac** and x264? since i can't seem to edit mkv metadata (when i remove from mediamonkey playlist, they're all gone), mp4 is fine though and i can't seem to play AAC, although it's fine when muxed into video

Answer (score 2):

Copy all custom and global metadata tag information using the following command:

```
ffmpeg <inputfile> -movflags use_metadata_tags -c copy  <outputfile>
```